# Burninate the [modification] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

Please burninate the [modification](/questions/tagged/modification) tag.

It doesn't add anything IMHO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]